# TYPO3 CKEditor : reduce the space between 2 lines

Tags: php, ckeditor, typo3

I am using CKEditor for my text content and I want to know how to reduce the space between 2 lines?
When I write content and press enter to go to next line I get a big space Like I pressed enter 2 times

thanks you for helping

Comment: It's called a paragraph. :) https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have only a line break instead of a new paragraph, press `Shift` + `Enter`.

That behaviour is similar in almost every (rich text) editor as well as in MS Word or Open Office / Libre Office.